# Suggest a plugin for up/down voting posts

Tags: plugins, stackoverflow

I need a free wordpress plugin that will allow the users to upvote or down vote every post. Something similar to stackoverflow.com

If not give me suggestions of how to create one. I am a java programmer and have never coded anything in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

[GD Star Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/) ( plugin is no longer in development ) was pretty comprehensive.

Comment: I'm not sure if wp-postratings does up/down voting, but GD Star Rating certainly does.

Answer (score 5):

For all of my rating uses i use WP-PostRatings

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer completely now, but i could achieve a vote on/off functionality by implementing a "custom comment type". 
It behaves very much like a comment, except it doesn't get listed/counted as a normal comment and can be retrieved independently from the comments table.

If you are interested I can post some code (quite some hacking into it, so i'll post it if there's some interest).

Comment: After many resaerches and thoughts, I feel this approach is good. +1 . I will edit your answer with my way of coding it, I hope you contribute.

Comment: Actually some time has passed, and I implemented such feature in a pretty large contest site with large user base (50.000 users). It proved a stable approach, i'll dig into the code if i find it and share the relevant parts. If you feel it's +1.. well click that up-arrow :D

Comment: :-D I don't know why my click on +1 didn't show, I am sure I made it, cuz really I am persuaded this is the approach. look at first comment here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100008/up-down-voting-system-for-wordpress

Comment: No probs, really jokin about +1. Can't post code right now, but can spend two words about it: if you need an easier but overloaded way of doing up/down voting, custom post types are the way to go. If, instead, you really need an atomic, clean and simple solution, comments-way will payback in terms of performance and backend management (yes, you can setup an area in the admin with tables dedicated to specific comment types). WP already has custom comment types, but they are sort of hardcoded. So, vote comments type will result too in not-that-clean code routines (at least they did for me).

Comment: I have please some questions: what do you mean by "will result too in not-that-clean code routines"? What do you think of the appraoch provided by Bainternet in the link I provided (using user meta) in terms of performance comparing with custom comment approach.